# Olap cube calculated member, how to round

Tags: mdx, olap, cube, olap-cube

I created  a calculated member and his value is:

```
[Measures].[Value]
/
[Measures].[Recuento Fact Result]
```

I want to round that value, and save only the first two decimals, 
for example:

```
[Measures].[Value]=10
[Measures].[Recuento Fact Result]=3
```

My calculated member = 3.3333333333333333333

I want to get 3.33

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Round(
  [Measures].[Value]/[Measures].[Recuento Fact Result]
  , 2  //<<you can adjust to the number of dec places required
)
```

Another interesting rounding function that is used in `mdx` is `Fix`

```
Fix(
  [Measures].[Value]/[Measures].[Recuento Fact Result]
)
```

You'll only get the integer part of the answer returned.

As an aside - you should defend against divide by zero possibilities with a measure like yours like this:

```
Round(
  IIF(
    [Measures].[Recuento Fact Result] = 0,
    ,null
    ,[Measures].[Value]/[Measures].[Recuento Fact Result]  
  )  
,2
)
```